# How does the Order of Scribes' Awakened Spellbook interact with Animate Objects?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, damage-types

The relevant part of awakened spellbook is:

> When you cast a wizard spell with a spell slot, you can temporarily replace its damage type with a type that appears in another spell in your spellbook, which magically alters the spell's formula for this casting only. The latter spell must be of the same level as the spell slot you expend.

My reading of the description of *animate objects* is that there's only one damage type that's part of the spell, and the others are just a suggested DM thing, so [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/179424/how-does-the-order-of-scribes-feature-awakened-spellbook-work-with-multiple-dama) doesn't apply. Can you replace the damage type of *animate objects* with another damage type from my spellbook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### *Animate objects* does not deal damage, animated objects do.

The spell *animate objects* creates creatures out of objects that can themselves deal damage by making attacks. But the spell itself does not deal damage, so there is no damage type to replace via Awakened Spellbook.